# Cross Stack References Issues and Best Practices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

in referencing this documentation:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/@aws-cdk/core/README.md#removing-automatic-cross-stack-references
I have 2 stacks in the same application.

ProducerStack: deploys a lambda
ConsumerStack: takes the lambda reference passed into the props.

If I update the lambda in the producer the deploy fails due to the reference blocking it.  If I am understanding correctly, I have to remove refs to the lambda in the consumer, deploy which will update the producer.  Then add refs back and deploy the consumer.

So questions are:
Are 2 deployments really needed in this case?
If so, is using cross stack references a bad idea?

More Info:
I have a single app that is one bounded context but I want to separate out the concerns.  Writing to s3 buckets, sending data to a vendor, and setting up on SQS.  SO I have these functionalities in separate stacks to practice good separation of concerns.  But this requires cross stack refs and I am now considering just making 1 huge stack.  I know I can break it up into modules and include them and thinking thats the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

> Is using cross stack references a bad idea?

Quite the opposite.  Cross-stack references are a [recommended CDK pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#%23best-practices-apps-names). They are a good fit for your scenario.

> Are 2 deployments really needed in this case?

This procedure is needed only if the CDK (or, more precisely, CloudFormation) needs to destroy (or replace = destroy + create) a resource used in another stack.  Fortunately, nearly all Lambda updates [do not require replacement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html). As such, deployment deadlocks (which are for our own protection) are rare. Name changes require a resource replacement - perhaps you changed the Lambda's logical id?

Comment: I must have caused a logical ID change, all I did is convert the lamdba from functional notation to fat arrow notation function lambda() {} to const lambda = () => {}

Comment: So in the providing stack I did a this.exportValue(lambda) and in the consuming stack am I supposed to remove all refs to the lamba?  If so, Im confused what the point of the export value is.

Comment: @screamingtiger An idiomatic approach to cross-stack-references is to simply [pass constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resource_stack) between stacks.  A "exporting" stack exposes a `lambda.Function` as [class instance field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_instance_fields) (`this.func = myLambda`). A second, "importing" stack accepts a `lambda.Function` as a prop (`handler: stack1.func`).  CDK makes makes the CloudFormation output/import refs for you at synth-time.

Comment: Yes I understand the issue is when I have to rename or remove a lambda.  No real clean way to do that without multiple deploys or deleting stacks in aws console.  Ill just have to be careful about renaming or anything that will cause logical id changes.